# Installing zlib1g-dev. Unmet dependency on libc-dev libc6-dev

Tags: apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install zlib1gdev on windows linux subsystem. I have already  done a dpkg --configure plus a update and upgrade. Hence, unfortunately first comment is no good.

and I get the error

```
    sudo apt-get install -f zlib1g-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 zlib1g-dev : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                       libc-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

so if I try to compare sources

```
    sudo apt-cache policy libc6-dev libc6 libc-dev libc

libc6-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.23-0ubuntu11
  Version table:
     2.23-0ubuntu11 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.23-0ubuntu10 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.23-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libc6:
  Installed: 2.27-3ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2.27-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2.27-3ubuntu1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.23-0ubuntu11 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.23-0ubuntu10 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.23-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libc-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
N: Unable to locate package libc
```

So to install libc6-dev then I need to downgrade libc6 but being as its the fundamental part of a system I get the warning

```
    You are about to do something potentially harmful
To continue type in the phrase ‘Yes, do as I say!’
 ?]
```

I am heading down the correct path and I should just downgrade libc6 or is there another way to solve this install problem.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following:

1) `dpkg --configure -a`

2) `apt-get update` and then reinstall your package.

Comment: Hi, I had already done so. Now explicitly stated in post.